# Converting PostgreSQL Subqueries into Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is an example schema with 3 tables.  I'm trying to run a query that returns all Jobs where all child Shifts are of status 6.  If a Job has a child Shift with a status of 5, the Job should not be returned.  The proper response for a query from the sample data inserted below is no rows returned.

There is a working query below with the comment "Works".  I am trying to refactor the "works" query to use joins instead of subqueries.  The query with the comment "Does not work" is my attempt.

```
-- begin setup and table creation: only run this section once.

CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE jobs
(
  id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  CONSTRAINT jobs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE bookings
(
  id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  job_id uuid,
  CONSTRAINT bookings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE shifts
(
  id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  booking_id uuid,
  status integer,
  CONSTRAINT shifts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into jobs (id) values ('e857c86c-bc31-11e6-9aae-57793f585d49');

insert into bookings (id, job_id) values ('736da82c-bc32-11e6-b9b8-f36753d321ac', 'e857c86c-bc31-11e6-9aae-57793f585d49');
insert into bookings (id, job_id) values ('7d839e5c-bc32-11e6-8bb3-4fa95be86a74', 'e857c86c-bc31-11e6-9aae-57793f585d49');

insert into shifts (booking_id, status) values ('736da82c-bc32-11e6-b9b8-f36753d321ac', 6);
insert into shifts (booking_id, status) values ('7d839e5c-bc32-11e6-8bb3-4fa95be86a74', 5);

-- end setup and table creation
```

We want all jobs where all child shifts are of status 6.  If a job has a child shift with a status of 5, the job should not be returned.  The proper response for a query from the sample data inserted above is no rows returned.

Does not work :(

```
SELECT "jobs".* 
FROM "jobs" 
   inner join bookings b1 on jobs.id = b1.job_id 
   inner join shifts s1 on b1.id = s1.booking_id 
   left outer join bookings b2 on jobs.id = b2.job_id 
   left outer join shifts s2 on b2.id = s2.booking_id and s2.status IN (2,3,4,5) 
WHERE s1.status = 6 
  AND s2.id IS NULL 
GROUP BY "jobs"."id";
```

Works

```
SELECT "jobs".*
FROM "jobs"
WHERE jobs.id IN (
    SELECT job_id
    FROM bookings
    WHERE bookings.id IN (
        SELECT booking_id FROM shifts WHERE status = 6
    )
) AND jobs.id NOT IN (
    SELECT job_id FROM bookings WHERE bookings.id IN (
        SELECT booking_id FROM shifts WHERE status IN (2,3,4,5)
    )
)
GROUP BY "jobs"."id";
```

How can I refactor the "works" query to use joins instead of subqueries?  The "does not work" query is my attempt.

Comment: What is the problem with your subquery approach?  The subqueries don't appear to be correlated, so from a performance point of view they may not be a big problem.

Comment: A join does not necessarily return the same result as a sub-query solution. So why do you want to re-write that?

Comment: You are probably coming from a mysql background where subqueries are almost always slower than joins. In postgresql it is not so. **you do not need to do this**

Answer (score 0):

Try this (haven't tested so there may be typos):

```
with prohibited_jobs as (
    select distinct jobs.id
    from jobs
        join bookings on jobs.id == bookings.job_id
        join shifts on shifts.booking_id = booking.job_id
    where shift.status != 6
)
select jobs.*
from jobs
    left outer join prohibited_jobs p on p.id = jobs.id
where
    p.id IS NULL
```

It's not completely free from subqueries (doing everything with joins would most certainly be less efficient), but it removes some unnecessary checks, so may be a little bit faster (which I suspect is your goal).

There is a small difference to your working query, in that it returns all jobs where all shifts have status 6 (as you said you want), whereas your query also ensures that the job has at least one shift (of status 6).